# Yoneda embedding and Horn sentences

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, limits-and-colimits, representable-functors, yoneda-lemma

The following is taken from Borceux and Bourn's *Mal'cev, Protomodular, Homological, and Semi-Abelian Categories*.

> **Metatheorem 0.1.3.** Let $\mathcal P$ be a statement of the form $\varphi\implies \psi$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ can be expressed as conjunctions of properties in the following list:
>
> 1. some finite diagram is commutative;
> 2. some morphism is a monomorphism;
> 3. some morphism is an isomorphism;
> 4. some finite diagram is a limit diagram;
> 5. an arrow $f:\rightarrow B$ factors (of course, uniquely) through some specified monomorphism $s:S\rightarrowtail B$.
>
> If this statement is valid in the category of sets, it is valid in every category.

After the proof comes the following remark.

> It is probably useful to make a comment. The list of properties in our metatheorem is not exhaustive. A better way to express the metatheorem would have been to state it for Horn sentences and the "unique existential quantifier $\exists!$", but we do not want to enter those considerations here.

I tried googling 'Yoneda embedding horn sentence' but didn't find anything I thought was relevant. What is the "better way to express the metatheorem", and why is it true? I'm guessing some topos theory comes in, but I don't really know anything about (the logical aspect of) it.

Comment: The unstated metatheorem is true because the Yoneda embedding preserves all limits and is fully faithful. Every one of the explicit examples listed can be proved using that fact, and many more besides.

Comment: @ZhenLin those are the properties I do know, but I don't know how they interact with Horn sentences. Could you briefly explain what Horn sentences are and why the interact well with limit preserving fully faithful functors?

Comment: Horn sentences are, roughly speaking, a logical way of thinking about finite limits.

Comment: @ZhenLin could you recommend a light, category-oriented introduction to the topic?

Comment: Not really. But you can find it in [_Sketches of an elephant_, Part D].

Comment: @ZhenLin I `ctrl f`'d "Horn" but got nothing. There's also no such entry in the index. Also, I just realized I don't see why the restriction to *finite* diagrams and limits is necessary - fully faithful functors reflect all commutative diagrams and limits.

Comment: See §D1.1. And it is in fact in the index.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks, I had a bad electronic copy. §D1.1 is beyond me. Could you explain why finiteness pops up?

Comment: I suggest you try to learn something about Horn sentences first.

Comment: @ZhenLin Respectfully, I think it's reasonable to ask why finiteness pops up (before diving into Horn sentences), since it has no mention in the proof of the metatheorem in the book, which seems to be elementary.

Comment: Finiteness is not relevant to the (unstated) metatheorem. It only appears in connection with Horn sentences.

Comment: @ZhenLin I take it the stated metatheorem does not hold with 'finite' omitted though, and I don't understand why.

Comment: In fact it holds without "finite".